# Select_tag: Style and Modify Options Upon Condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `form_categories` table which has a column called `active` which is of type tinyint/boolean. If the form category record's active attribute is true, then it is active. If false, then it is inactive.

I have a select box that displays **all** of the records within the `form_categories` table. I want to style the `inactive` form_category options red in order to convey to the user that that form_category is inactive.  Or Even better, I'd like to put in parentheses next to each inactive form_category option: `(inactive)` in red letters.

Is this possible?

Below is my select box:

```
<%= form_tag some_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= label_tag "Choose Category" %><br>
  <%= select_tag :category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(FormCategory.all, :id, :name), include_blank: true %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) and provide the options hash yourself:

```
options_for_select(form_categories_options, 1) # Where 1 is the current selected option; you would use some value passed from the controller for it
```

For `form_categories_options`, you can use a helper, like:

```
def form_categories_options
  FormCategory.all.map do |form_category|
    if form_category.inactive
      ["#{form_category.name} (inactive)", form_category.id]
    else
      [form_category.name, form_category.id]
    end
  end
end
```

If you really want to use [`options_from_collection_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select), you can tweak the third argument, namely the `text_method`: you can define a `formatted_name` method in your `FormCategory` model:

```
class FormCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def formatted_name
    if inactive
      "#{name} (inactive)"
    else
      name
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

then use it:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(FormCategory.all, :id, :formatted_name)
```

Comment: This looks great for appending (inactive) to the inactive options!  Do you know how to style only the inactive options red?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible. See also this other SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7208786/433940. You may look at alternatives, such as Select2, but there is no way to style `<option>`s inside a `<select>`.